# Why is the plot not showing up?

Tags: plotting

[image: Code]

Does anyone know why my plot is not showing up? I get a recursion error.

```
ω = Range[0, 5, 1];
U = 0;
μ = 0;
Σ[ω_] := 0;
G[ω_] := 0.5*(ω + μ - Σ[ω]) + 0.5*Sqrt[(ω + μ - Σ[ω]) ^2 - 4];
G0[ω_] := ((G[ω])^(-1) + Σ[ω]);
Gnew[ω_] := 0.5*G0[ω] + 0.5*( (G0[ω])^(-1) - U)^(-1);
Σ[ω_] := (G0[ω])^(-1) - (G[ω])^(-1);

Plot[Im[G[ω]], {ω, 0, 5}]
```

Comment: It would be much easier to answer if you placed the code as text rather than as an image. But you might try Evaluate[Im[G[omega]]

Comment: You have `G` depending on `\[CaptialSigma]` and `\[CapitalSigma]` depending on `G`, leading to a recursion error.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of how you redefine `Σ[ω]`.  If we take a look at the [`DownValues`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html) of `G`

```
S[x_] := 0
G[x_] := 0.5 (x - S[x]) + 0.5 Sqrt[(x - S[x])^2 - 4]
DownValues@G
G0[x_] := G[x]^-1 + S[x]
S[x_] := G0[x]^-1 - G[x]^-1
```

> {HoldPattern[G[x_]] :> 0.5 (x - S[x]) + 0.5 Sqrt[(x - S[x])^2 - 4]}

we can see that the previously defined `S[x]` isn't explicitly replaced with 0 as you may have wanted, but rather with the unevaluated function.  Since this is the case, you can redefine `S` later and not have to change the definition of `G`.  Which is exactly what happened.

Since any time `G` is called, `S` is also called, and every time `S` is called, `G` is called again.  So there is an infinite loop whenever you call `G`.  That's why there is recursion error.